# Application not visible in menu

Tags: android

I am working on an android Dialer My MainActivity's intent-filter is given bellow

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
            <data android:scheme="tel"  />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

after adding these filters my application is not seeing in phone menu.

```
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
            <data android:scheme="tel"  />
```

please tell me why??

Comment: I have separated it into two intent-filters like Vang said. Now the App is visible in phone Menu... But now the other 'android.intent.action.DIAL' intents cant find the my Activity for that action

Answer (score 2):

Try to separate your intent-filters in two:

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
            <data android:scheme="tel"  />
  </intent-filter>

  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

It seems Android considers your filters as one.

Comment: Hi now I got one issue... now the application not responds for DIAL action from other apps